# Работа с сайтом vk.com

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, chrome-extension, вконтакте

Ребят, привет! Подскажите, как можно реализовать данное действие: заходишь в браузер Chrome на сайт vk.com, при нажатии на кнопку новости непосредственно переходила на новости но через секунды 2 нажималась сама кнопка мои сообщения. Можно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Можно. Реализовывайте.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать собственное расширение под Chrome – "[Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)". Это javascript файл, который будет подключаться, когда вы зайдёте ВКонтакт, будто бы он часть страницы.

У себя в Хроме наберите `chrome://extensions/` и включите Developer Mode. Создайте папку, где будет лежать [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) и скрипт. Когда создадите манифест и скрипт, нажмите кнопку Load unpacked extension.. и укажите эту папку.

В скрипте нужно повесить таймер и раз пять в секунду смотреть адрес страницы `location.pathname`, и если он изменился на "/feed", запускать таймер на 2 секунды, который перебросит на "/im" – в Сообщения.

У меня получился вот [такой экстеншн](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3533396/hashcode/vkMsg.crx), работает, вроде.